# Possible to make a new (blog) page in CMS drupal?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

---

Lets say that my customer is a blogger and wants to make daily blogs. So that means she needs a way to add new pages in the CMS. I dont want a customer to do technically stuff obviously. It needs to be as easy as it can get.

And I heard that drupal is a great CMS. So i'm open for that adventure. But before I take that road, I'm wondering if this is possible to do in a drupal CMS?
I'm new to drupal and to its CMS. So I don't know which version to take. Or anything at all. So I want to know for sure if this is possible before I spent hours and it isn't possible.

IF there is another cms you recommend, you can mention it. I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term **CMS** itself says that the purpose of this type of software is to manage content - exactly what you're looking for. So Drupal or any other CMS also provides the ability to create blogs and easy-to-use administrator features.

About Drupal, it is a powerful and flexible CMS, suitable for creating many complex features as well as scalability. If you just need a lightweight blogs page with basic features like content CRUD, you can take a look at Wordpress.

If you choose Drupal, I recommend using the latest version (Drupal 9) for the long-term support.

Comment: Could you look at - https://app.slack.com/client/T06GX3JTS/C1BMUQ9U6/thread/C1BMUQ9U6-1620819163.145500

Comment: Im wondering, since you are saying Drupal 9 is the latest version. I realised, a year ago i heard about Drupal 8. So im wondering, when Drupal releases a new version, is it easy to upgrade? (Like was it easy to upgrade from Drupal 5 to 6 to 7 to 8 and now 9, you get the point). And because all of this is Open Source, im wondering, is there a catch?